# Support library and compileSdkVersion version mismatch

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle, android-glide

I am buidling an application and I am using my old HTC Desire S to debug and test the application. On this phone runs Android version 2.3.5, and the minimum SDK of my application is set on 10.

Also, because of these awesome specs, my phone has trouble when importing JPEGs, as a bitmap, in ImageView (probably because of the size of the JPEGs), and crashes when handling certain files.

```
   public void showImage() {
            String filePath = contentDirectory + "/" + filesInFolder[image_index];
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

After some searching around I figured that I should use Glide to fix my issues.

Following the instructions on the Glide GitHub page, I insert the following in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

And dislplay the image as:

```
public void showImage() {
        String filePath = contentDirectory + "/" + filesInFolder[image_index];
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        Glide.with(this).load(filePath).into(imgView);
}
```

When running my application, it crashes. I therefore changed `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` into `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:10.3.1'` (version 25 into 10).

I now get the error

> This support library should not use a different version (10) than the
>   compileSdkVersion (25)

And I therefore set compileSdkVersion to 10:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXX.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

After syncing the gradle file, I get a whole lot of errors, all of them are located within

> C:...\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\

If necessary I can post them all (there are many), but I think that the main issue here is that I get the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Is there anyone who can provide a solution or point me in the right direction?

Crashdump at line:

> Glide.with(this).load(filePath).into(imgView);

```
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide; interface 59 'Landroid/content/ComponentCallbacks2;'
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide;' failed
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with, referenced from method com.imageviewexample.ImageViewExample.showImage
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 17289: Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide;.with (Landroid/app/Activity;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager;
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0028
01-06 04:05:13.929 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: dead code 0x002b-0033 in Lcom/imageviewexample/ImageViewExample;.showImage ()V
01-06 04:05:13.959 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-06 04:05:13.959 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
01-06 04:05:13.969 21324-21324/com.example.XXX.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bumptech.glide.Glide
                                                                                           at com.imageviewexample.ImageViewExample.showImage(ImageViewExample.java:78)
                                                                                           at com.imageviewexample.ImageViewExample.onCreate(ImageViewExample.java:53)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: So why did you change from version 25 to 10?

Comment: because I assumed that my application crashed at startup because it couldnt handle version 25, since it is running on android 2.3.5

Comment: Delete **<project-folder>/app/build** folder, and try to rebuild the project again and see if it works btw why did you change support lib version its totally unrelated i far as i know, post your crash logs may be we can resolve them.

Comment: @daan166 while that could be the case you always want to be targeting the latest version of android. You should have posted your original error first before doing all this other stuff

Comment: First of all revert the build tool version and compile sdk version to 25 again like it was before. After syncing post the error that it shows.

Comment: After setting everything back to 25, and debugging again, I conluded that it crashes at the line: Glide.with(this).load(filePath).into(imgView);. However, I havent figured out how to retrieve crash reports from android 2.3.

Comment: Figured it out to get the dump, Ill post it in the original question

Comment: May be your app is exceeding 64k methods limit, try to enable multidex and see if it works

Comment: I did the following in build.gradle (as I suppose that I enable multidex like this), but it didnt work:               
android {
         defaultConfig {
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

Comment: Also in Android Manifest in application tag you need to add **name=".MultidexApplication"** or something like that

Comment: I included the line within android manifest, and unfortunetely it crashed again

Comment: thanks for the input guys, I decided to not implement Glide, instead I solved the memory issue using bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me using Glide in the first place was a memory issue with bitmaps and ImageView. Unfortunately I and the helpful members above, were not able to solve the issue regarding the Glide crash as described above.

Rather than that I went back to my first problem, which was the memory issue, and solved that by including `bitmap.recycle()` within my code the moment a new bitmap was displayed.